# How to add "\n" line by line in string html with python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, string, replace

I have one line html formatted like this:

```
<ol class="X5LH0c"><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Create A Bakery Business Plan. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Choose A Location For Your Bakery Business. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Get All Licenses Required To Open A Bakery Business In India. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Get Manpower Required To Open A Bakery. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Buy Equipment Needed To Start A Bakery Business.</li></ol>
```

The HTML code will have attribute class and id unspecified. I need to add "\n" line by line when closed HTML code.
My code in Python is this:

```
TAGS = ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'li', 'img','ol']
SINGLE_LINE_TAGS = ['ul', 'ol']
INLINE_TAGS = ['strong', 'i', 'u', 'em']

html = '''<ol class="X5LH0c"><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Create A Bakery Business Plan. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Choose A Location For Your Bakery Business. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Get All Licenses Required To Open A Bakery Business In India. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Get Manpower Required To Open A Bakery. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Buy Equipment Needed To Start A Bakery Business.</li></ol>'''

for tag in TAGS:
    html = html.replace('</{}>'.format(tag), '</{}>\n'.format(tag))

for tag in SINGLE_LINE_TAGS:
    html = html.replace('<{}>'.format(tag), '<{}>\n'.format(tag))
    html = html.replace('</{}>'.format(tag), '</{}>\n'.format(tag))

html = html.replace(' />', ' />\n')

print(html)
```

But the result is:

```
<ol class="X5LH0c"><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Create A Bakery Business Plan. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Choose A Location For Your Bakery Business. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe">Get All Licenses Required To Open A Bakery Business In India. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe">Get Manpower Required To Open A Bakery. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe">Buy Equipment Needed To Start A Bakery Business.</li>
</ol>
```

Why isn't it this:

```
<ol class="X5LH0c">
<li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Create A Bakery Business Plan. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Choose A Location For Your Bakery Business. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe">Get All Licenses Required To Open A Bakery Business In India. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe">Get Manpower Required To Open A Bakery. ... </li>
<li class="TrT0Xe">Buy Equipment Needed To Start A Bakery Business.</li>
</ol>
```

I don't use regex. Can anyone help me fix the code? Thanks for your support!

Comment: You are replacing `<ol>`, but you have `<ol class="X5LH0c">`

Comment: Firstly, why are you even doing this? HTML is not supposed to be pretty-printed because it is intended to be parsed by your browser, not by you. Second, "<ol class="X5LH0c">" does not match any of your tag names because it has an attribute. You must use _something like_ regular expressions to solve the problem, but even they are not a perfect tool. Consider studying BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Regular expressions are not even the *right* tool, let alone a perfect tool, for manipulating HTML.

Comment: How do you mean "The HTML code will have attribute class and id unspecified."? The given code clearly has them specified.

Comment: Thansk all for your help! I will try with regex and BeautifulSoup. Thanks Maurice Meyer, DYZ, chepner, and The_spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is the following.

```
TAGS = ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'li', 'img','ol']
SINGLE_LINE_TAGS = ['ul', 'ol']
INLINE_TAGS = ['strong', 'i', 'u', 'em']

html = '''<ol class="X5LH0c"><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Create A Bakery Business Plan. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe" id="hello">Choose A Location For Your Bakery Business. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Get All Licenses Required To Open A Bakery Business In India. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Get Manpower Required To Open A Bakery. ... </li><li class="TrT0Xe">Buy Equipment Needed To Start A Bakery Business.</li></ol>'''

# Xuống dòng mỗi thẻ
for tag in TAGS:
    html = html.replace('<{}'.format(tag), '\n<{}'.format(tag))

for tag in SINGLE_LINE_TAGS:
    html = html.replace('<{}>'.format(tag), '\n<{}>'.format(tag))
    html = html.replace('</{}>'.format(tag), '\n</{}>'.format(tag))

print(html)
```

So, I have replaced the search of a closing-bracket `</{}>` to the search of a opening-bracket `<{}`, and switched the placement of the newline character before the opening bracket (so that `<li class ...` is also replaced).

This produced an extra line at the start of the html file, which you can get rid of using `html = html[1:]`.

A more elegant solution would be to use regex replacements, but it all depends on the exact output you desire.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your help! It work with me sir! I will try with regex later, because I think regex is slow and something I need simple way to fix that. String is ok but when work with HTML tag very diffucult, I will try with regex like you sharing.